# where condition to return some value if not match found

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, where-clause, outer-join

```
SELECT
  PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID,
  PIPELINE_STEP_ID
FROM
  PROJECT_ESTIMATES
WHERE
  PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID='29ab9760-c75b-4479-882c-bc84426d55ac';
```

This gives the following output

[image]

and

by using where condition with other class,

```
SELECT
  PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID,
  MPS.STEP_DESCRIPTION
FROM
  PROJECT_ESTIMATES PE,
  MST_PIPELINE_STEPS MPS 
WHERE
  PE.`PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID` ='29ab9760-c75b-4479-882c-bc84426d55ac' 
  AND PE.`TENANT_ID`='{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000'
  AND PE.PIPELINE_STEP_ID=MPS.PIPELINE_STEP_ID
ORDER BY
  PE.MODIFIED_DATE DESC;
```

gives the following output.

[image]

I would like to get step_description as 0 for the first record which has PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID value as 046a190e-a895-4ce2-bb10-7a583d648b99.ie,the below pic shows the desired output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question, this will work:

```
SELECT 
PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID,
IF(
PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID = '046a190e-a895-4ce2-bb10-7a583d648b99', 
0,
PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID) AS STEP_DESCRIPTION
FROM 
PROJECT_ESTIMATES PE, 
MST_PIPELINE_STEPS MPS 
WHERE PE.`PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID` ='29ab9760-c75b-4479-882c-bc84426d55ac' 
AND PE.`TENANT_ID`='{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000' 
AND PE.PIPELINE_STEP_ID=MPS.PIPELINE_STEP_ID 
ORDER BY PE.MODIFIED_DATE DESC
```

Unless of course you meant you want zero rather than blank or null in which case this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID
IF(
LENGTH
(ISNULL(
PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID,'')) > 0,
PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID, 0) AS STEP_DESCRIPTION
FROM PROJECT_ESTIMATES PE, 
     MST_PIPELINE_STEPS MPS 
WHERE PE.`PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID` ='29ab9760-c75b-4479-882c-bc84426d55ac' 
AND PE.`TENANT_ID`='{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000' 
AND PE.PIPELINE_STEP_ID=MPS.PIPELINE_STEP_ID 
ORDER BY PE.MODIFIED_DATE DESC
```

Comment: hi.sorry for your misunderstanding.please see the added image(desired output) above.

Comment: My answers were not a far cry from what you're looking for, I've modified them per your requirements.

Comment: hi @alan error while executing the sql.Query: SELECT PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID IF(LENGTH(ISNULL(PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID,'')) > 0,PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID, 0) AS STEP_DESCRIPTION...

Error Code: 1064

Answer (score 0):

This query satisfies my requirement.

```
SELECT PE.PROJECT_ESTIMATES_ID, MPS.STEP_DESCRIPTION
FROM PROJECT_ESTIMATES PE
LEFT JOIN MST_PIPELINE_STEPS MPS
ON PE.PIPELINE_STEP_ID=MPS.PIPELINE_STEP_ID WHERE
PE.`PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID` ='29ab9760-c75b-4479-882c-bc84426d55ac'
AND PE.`TENANT_ID`='{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000' 
ORDER BY PE.MODIFIED_DATE DESC ;
```